# mysql calculate total minutes in perticular hours

Tags: mysql

i have a data like

```
    2017-03-22 10:57:01
    2017-03-22 10:57:09
    2017-03-22 10:59:35
    2017-03-22 10:59:55
    2017-03-22 11:00:01
    2017-03-22 11:08:16
    2017-03-22 11:39:07
    2017-03-22 11:50:37
    2017-03-22 11:59:57
   ..........
ex. 10 AM total minutes worked 45

    tracking_dtls 

  device_id    tracking_dt_time
        1        2017-03-22 10:57:01
        1        2017-03-22 10:57:09
        1        2017-03-22 10:59:35
        1        2017-03-22 10:59:55
        1        2017-03-22 11:00:01
        1        2017-03-22 11:08:16
        1        2017-03-22 11:39:07
        1        2017-03-22 11:50:37
        1        2017-03-22 11:59:57

From tracking_dtls  table calculate total working minutes for a all hours
```

In this data calculate working minutes for all hours seprately.how can i do that can somebody please help me.

Comment: Please add the table structure and how you would like the result of your query to look like.

Comment: Will you able to do anything if someone gives data like that to do?

Comment: " time 10 total minutes worked 45" what does that mean?

Comment: between 10 AM to 11 AM total working minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do group by hearly and take the difference of time max minus min.

```
select HOUR(tracking_dt_time),
(TIME_TO_SEC(max(tracking_dt_time))-TIME_TO_SEC(min(tracking_dt_time)))/60 as minutes from tracking_dtls group by HOUR(tracking_dt_time)
```

Comment: thnks for u r answer